# Bootstrap form labels not placed before the textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not seeing why the following code is putting the labels to the right of the textbox instead of the to the left? Should I be using `<div class="row">` around the `<div class="form-group">`?

Anyone know what I'm missing?

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditClockGroup", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupId, null)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupId, new { @class = "col-md-7 form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupName, new { @class = "col-md-7 form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You should look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) at the bootstrap docs for forms under the "control sizing" section. You should look at the "Horizontal form group sizes" part. It looks like they are nesting the `.form-control` in a `col-` not adding it to the class of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply ***col-md-7*** to ***input*** tag. Instead, you need to place ***input*** inside ***div***.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GroupId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-7">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GroupId, new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That's the way the code was when I found it in an example but thinking I knew better I thought it looked cleaner to add the col-md-7 to the Textbox class like the label.